# Is is stupid to store large amounts of images in a database?

Tags: database, storage

I'm having a dilemma with allowing users to upload images to my application. My host allows unlimited storage space, but only allows 250k individual files. I'm at 125k, and I'm planning on releasing a feature that will allow users to upload images. If I start getting a large amounts of images uploaded, I could quickly fill that quota up. I thought about storing them in a database such as MySQL. Is this a feasible solution, or just plain stupid? If it's just stupid, what would be some free/cheap alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, putting the image data in a db would be kind of silly.
I'd look at using something like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for storage.

Here's a [CodingHorror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/using-amazon-s3-as-an-image-hosting-service.html) post from years ago where Jeff discusses it.

Comment: That looks like my best option. And it's uber cheap. I don't think the bandwith cost will be as much of a problem as my storage. :P. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using database is obviously more slow than using the filesystem. If you already have 125k maybe it will be a good idea to use VPS instead of hosting. It's about 5-10$/mon.

Comment: http://www.hetzner.de/hosting/produkte_vserver/vq7 (i use this one for my little needs)

Comment: Holy crap that is awesome. I may end up using that for some side projects.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of good reasons to store images (or any bulky media files) outside the database.

The reasons you *would* store images in the database are if you need image data to work with SQL ACID semantics.

For example, if you insert a row in a database, but rollback, you would want the image data to also be discarded.  If you store the image data externally to the database, you have to clean up orphaned images.
Likewise if you DELETE rows from the database, you also have to remember to delete them from the disk or S3 or whatever.
Likewise if you UPDATE rows, you lose transaction isolation, so you have race conditions.

Also creating database backups is more complex if you store images outside the database.  Not only because now your backup is a multi-step process (backup database and then backup image collection), but also you can't create hot backups.  Your image collection might be changing during the minutes while the backup is copying data from the database.

Comment: +1 For some really useful information. Since this isn't a major enterprise project, I don't think I have to worry about needing to store the images in a database. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't do that. It will end up causing you more problems later on.
Why don't you sign up to http://www.000webhost.com/ (or similar) and create a script to upload images there instead of your server? It's what I would do.

Or, you could start setting limits on how long images are kept for? and delete them after x days?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option for you to store the images on a CDN, or something like s3?  Get the images off your server and get the benefits of the fast infrastructure.  More here: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

Gets more complicated if you need to secure images but all doable.